# How to edit the text "grand total" in email template

Tags: email-templates, sales-order-view

I would like to change the text "Grand Total" to just "Total" in my email template.

[image]

The thing is though I have to edit {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order_id=$order_id area="frontend"}}

I am not sure if I found this path correctly, but I edited
/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/template/order/totals.phtml
please check the code image below
[image]

Did I edit the correct file? if not please help me where I can edit this.
It's sort of frustrating that I can't really check in preview template.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, you are on righ path, but you must override this same template class, or if you want to save your time try to make edit *grand total in same vendor template file* and place test order and check your email, after that you can easily override it in your custom module.
Thankyou.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Zahid. I don't understand I must override this same template class. Can you tell me where I can edit the class?

Comment: Step1: override this class in your module: /vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/template/order/totals.phtml 
Step2: override this class vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_shipment_items.xml
step3: override this class: vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/order_new.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Step1: override this class: in your module: /vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/template/order/totals.phtml 

Step2: override this class: vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_shipment_items.xml

step3: override this class: vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/order_new.html
```

and makes changes according to your module and carefully change names where required.

Comment: I wish I could give you an upvote. Thank you

Comment: I am just curious. What will happen if I don't override??

Comment: I cannot make changes in core file, to make changes or customization we always need to override a class.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense lol thank you so much!